# What are some good free CSV editor programs?

Tags: windows, csv

I deal with CSV files all the time.  I have been using excel, but it's not really made for csv's.  Is there a program out there that deals with just csv's and data shaping?

Comment: I have made a simple tool at http://csvmagic.com/ that deals with CSV using JavaScript.

Comment: The question is very valuable (if badly posed) and should be re-opened.  Spreadsheet applications try to be too clever in guessing datatypes, and often get it wrong (turning phone numbers into exponential numbers, for example).  A good plain CSV editor is potentially a very powerful tool for certain types of data programmers.

Comment: [30 Best Free CSV Editor Software For Windows](http://listoffreeware.com/list-of-best-free-csv-editor-software-for-windows/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in my opinion [openoffice](http://www.openoffice.org/) ([libre office](http://www.libreoffice.org)) are far better and have way more capabilities.

Comment: gonna give libre office a try!

Comment: Does OpenOffice/LibreOffice have the same annoyance as Excel where it tries to guess the data format of each entry and e.g. lose leading zeros? The ideal CSV editor would leave everything as a string.

Comment: well i just tried it, and i love it so far.  when you open a csv file you get a whole buncha options on how to handle the csv file.  its perfect for what i need. thanks!

Comment: Note: OpenOffice has the same row limit issues that Microsoft Excel does. I've been looking for an alternative CSV editor and ran into the same problem on both programs.

Comment: @Seb Is there a way to always open the file with UTF-8 encoding ? It always asks for options when opening a file. Thanks.

Comment: does this help you in any way? http://superuser.com/questions/120102/set-csv-import-default-to-utf-8-in-calc to be honest I did never think about this issue ;)

Answer (score 19):

I have written a product called [Ron's Editor](http://www.ronsplace.eu/Products/RonsEditor) which you might want to look at. I am always interested in making it more useful/powerful so I would be interested in your feedback.

Comment: Hi Aaron, you have a nice csv editor. But it seems like it is not possible to insert a multi line value in a cell.

Comment: Is there a simple way to reorder rows? I'm looking for something like a "move selected row up" and "move selected row down" button.

Comment: Just so everyone knows; you can only save 1000 rows with the free edition.

Comment: Ron's editor was also able to open CSV with very long lines and almost 2000 columns. Something that Excel and OpenOffice could not manage. Also nice feature is that if you copy a line, the header is copied as well (so you get two lines which you can then paste somewhere else).

Comment: Is there a way to open pipe-separated files?

Comment: This is the best editor I've found so far to properly edit multiline text cells.

Answer (score 1):

[Quattro Pro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quattro_Pro), [Open Office.org Calc (Libre Office)](http://www.openoffice.org/product/calc.html), [Lotus Symphony Spreadsheets](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/lotus/symphony/home.nsf/product_sse) and [PlanMaker Mobile](http://www.softmaker.net/down/pm2012manual_en.pdf) are some great csv editors and spreadsheet programs.

Here are there details: [A Collection of Free Spreadsheet Programs](http://ulancer.com/2011/03/some-spreadsheet-programs-that-can-help-you-to-work-with-huge-lists-and-calculations/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have to manage a lot of string data in my job, and using spreadsheet programs can be trouble unless you take great care to stop if from guessing data types.

Most of the time I do use MS Excel. But occasionally I'll drop into [CSVed](http://csved.sjfrancke.nl/), such as when I have a field that exceeds the character limit. The reason I prefer MS Excel is because most of the time inline editing of a field is much faster than the way CSVed has you do it.